# Reading a png image out of a pipe

Tags: julia

Let's say I have a pipe containing a PNG image. To be specific, using the Graphs package

```rb
using Graphs
G = erdos_renyi_graph(12, 0.1; is_directed=false)
outp, inp, proc = readandwrite(`neato -Tpng`)
Graphs.to_dot(G, inp)
close(inp)
```

Now outp is a pipe containing the raw image data. How to I read it into an Image with Images.jl or alternatively how do I display it directly with IJulia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could finally figure it out using Base.HTML and base64-conversion the same way as Base.Markdown does...

```rb
data = readbytes(outp)

Base.HTML() do io
    print(io, """<img src="data:image/png;base64,""")
    print(io, stringmime(MIME"image/png"(), data))
    print(io, "\" />")
end
```